# Windows 10: SetProcessDpiAwareness has no effect

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, dpi, dpi-aware

My Operating System is Windows 10 Enterprise.

[assembly: DisableDpiAwareness] is set in AssemblyInfo.cs

I am setting SetProcessDpiAwareness() to PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE = 2 and get S_OK = 0 back.

After that I call GetProcessDpiAwareness() and get PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE = 0 back.

Why is GetProcessDpiAwareness() PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE and why is my process not responding to DPI calls? How can I debug this issue?

Comment: What UI framework did you use? Windows Forms, WPF?

Comment: I use WPF as UI framework.

Comment: target for 4.6.2, here WPF apps are per monitor aware by definition: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39218709/1466046

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Application Blurry on High DPI Screen on Windows 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217355/wpf-application-blurry-on-high-dpi-screen-on-windows-10)

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148151/setprocessdpiawareness-not-having-effect

Comment: I can maximally target to 4.6.1. As written in my question, I have added [assembly: DisableDpiAwareness]. Thanks for the tipp, I will try whether GetLastWin32Error returns an error and write back on tuesday.

Comment: why can't you target 4.6.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that SetProcessDpiAwareness() needs to be called before any Win32-action. I had a toast notification window open before calling it.